# FreeIPA Web UI not listening on IPv4

Tags: freeipa

I installed FreeIPA on a VM. I went through the configuration and registered a client with `ipa-client-install`. After adding some users and groups on the IPA server I have confirmed that it is functioning properly.

During the configuration there was no question asking which IPs the server should be listening on. Most of the services (kerberos, dns, smtp, etc) are set up to listen on both of the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. I haven't actually configured IPv6, though so it is only really listening on the link-local address.

If I telnet to port 80 either locally via localhost or remotely via the IPv4 address and send a `GET` the response tells me that the "document has moved" with a link to the https URL. But, since it isn't listening on port 443 at the IPv4 address I'm unable to get to it.

Also, despite being able to telnet to port 80 remotely, if I attempt to navigate to the same IP in my browser I get "Server not found". Same result if I navigate to the https URL.

How can I configure the Web UI to listen on IPv4? I only need port 443.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I thought IPA was running a tomcat server for the web interface. I think I was confusing it with another application I recently installed.

After paying closer attention to the installation output I realized it is only running `httpd` which made fixing this a lot easier.